# nodejs graphviz: graph.output() converter giving error during DOT to PNG conversion

Tags: node.js, visualization, graphviz

```
graphviz = require('graphviz');
var g = graphviz.digraph("G");

// Add node (ID: Hello)
var n1 = g.addNode( "Hello", {"color" : "blue"} );
n1.set( "style", "filled" );

// // Add node (ID: World)
g.addNode( "World" );

// // Add edge between the two nodes
var e = g.addEdge( n1, "World" );
e.set( "color", "red" );

// // Print the dot script
console.log( g.to_dot() );
g.setGraphVizPath("/usr/local/bin")
g.output("png", "test.png")
```

Error

> node:events:490
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
> ^
>
> Error: spawn dot ENOENT
> at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:285:19)
> at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:483:16)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
> Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
> at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
> at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:483:16)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
> errno: -2,
> code: 'ENOENT',
> syscall: 'spawn dot',
> path: 'dot',
> spawnargs: [ '-Tpng', '-otest.png' ]
> }

Tried upgrading and downgrading node version, tried using rendererDot module for conversion, nothing worked. DOT file is not getting converted to SVG/PNG.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.